# why output nothing by invoke A a(A())?

Tags: c++

I want to konw what happened in this code? And, what diffrent to invoke A a(other).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define LOG() (cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl)

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() { LOG(); }
    A(const A&) { LOG(); }
    const A& operator=(const A&) { LOG(); }
};

int main(void)
{
    A a(A());
    return 0;
}
```

output nothing.

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), try `A a(A{});` instead.

Comment: That's the shortest question (including [mcve]) I've ever seen about this topic... Respect. ;-)